# Get salable quantities for all products via REST API

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4, quantity, salable

For synchronizing inventory levels with the external ERP, I need to know the quantities and booked quantities of all products. I can easily get quantities of all products with one request (`rest/all/V1/inventory/source-items`).

It seems that instead of getting the total amount of booked items per product, it is easier to get salable quantities. I have found several alternative ways how to get a salable quantity per one product. But none of them allow to get quantities per many products.

Is this possible to get the total amount of booked or not booked items for all products?

Thanks!